# What arrayformula can I put in a Google Spreadsheet cell to count cells with contents horizontally?

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula

Here's a link to the spreadsheet (anyone with link can view)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sjDh68rIO16bKs9VhtYgQh1QpAHSvwWRX7TjY0PVAmY/edit#gid=0

[image]

I basically need an arrayformula to put in cell L2 to have the same results in col J

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(E2:I4="",,1)),,9^9)), " ", )))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your your contribution, will try this today as well

Comment: Although this isn't an arrayformula, I found this shorter achieving the same results

Comment: @RodneyZanoria it is an "arrayformula", it just doesnt' use the Arrayformula() function because player0 insists on using INDEX() because it's less letters.  I believe it will be slower on large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an if to convert each column into numbers and just sum it up. Try applying the formula below to your sheet.

`=arrayformula(if($B$2:$B="","",if($E$2:$E="",0,1)+if($F$2:$F="",0,1)+if($G$2:$G="",0,1)+if($H$2:$H="",0,1)+if($I$2:$I="",0,1)))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks let me try this today and see if it works with the actual sheet :)

Comment: @RodneyZanoria just need to copy and paste the formula in :)

Comment: Hey @RodneyZanoria was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

you might try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="tiktok", MMULT(LEN(LEFT(E2:I)),{1;1;1;1;1}),))
```

Comment: This isn't working