# Count cells with content horizontally if the date is today

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula

This is related to my previous question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72758180/what-arrayformula-can-i-put-in-a-google-spreadsheet-cell-to-count-cells-with-con) but this time I want an arrayformula (or better) that I can place on the top cell of the column to count the cells on the left if Column A or Date Submitted is dated today.

I'll be adding another column to count if dated yesterday. I'm assuming use of today() and today()-1 would do it?

Here is the sample Google Spreadsheets [Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dTRoPj0xlosyat5ij9wcXD0CHbB3DD9gr2CzkfuO-rY/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Hi, can you visually clarify the expected outcome? A screenshot and/or specifying it on the spreadsheet sample might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula you can use to count if the date is today:

```js
=ArrayFormula(MMULT(n(ARRAYFORMULA(if((A2:A=today())*(E2:I<>"")>0, 1, ))),(transpose(COLUMN(E2:I)^0))))
```

[image: ex]

The extra `0`s can be gotten rid of with a simple `IF()` statement:

```js
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A<>today(),,MMULT(n(ARRAYFORMULA(if((A2:A=today())*(E2:I<>"")>0, 1, ))),(transpose(COLUMN(E2:I)^0)))))
```

[image: ex]

---

Also, as you mentioned, `today()-1` does work for finding yesterday:

```js
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A<>today()-1,,MMULT(n(ARRAYFORMULA(if((A2:A=today()-1)*(E2:I<>"")>0, 1, ))),(transpose(COLUMN(E2:I)^0)))))
```

[image: ex]

---

###### References:

###### - https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/array-formula-to-sum-multiple-columns-in-google-sheets/